# CheckBox Click event not fired (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, checkbox, click

I placed some **CheckBox**es in *UniformGrid*. I also modified stretch first checkbox like on this screenshot:

[image: UniformGrid]

I wrote **click event handler** for selected checkbox (image above). It's vertical and horizontal alignment is **Stretch**. But event handler fires only if I click precisely on checkbox. I want to be able fire the event if I click anywhere in the area of **(0,0)** cell.

Comment: Does your CheckBox have a Background Color?

Comment: The solution for this question is a duplicate of this question you asked earlier today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018014/center-checkbox-in-uniformgrids-cells-in-wpf

Comment: No, it's not. It's another problem. The same screenshot only.

Answer (score 0):

Add to cell  (0,0) grid with transparent background and on mouse up\down event will be fired.